# How do I achieve an infinite loop without breaking my code?

Tags: c#

I'm no programmer but I needed to make an executable for a program I use, I wrote it in C#.
When I launch or test debug it, it freezes at some point.

I need this executable to keep running forever basically, that's why I made an infinite while loop. I think this is where the problem is caused.

I need the program to do a check if the `oldctime` is equal to the `newctime` (checks if a file has been overwritten) if that happens it needs to run the `AddiLogic()` Sub.

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks in advance

```
 public InventorInfo() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            this.Close();
        }

        void RunProgram(object sender, EventArgs e) {    //LAUNCH BUTTON press
           
            while (LaunchedApp == false) {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text)) {
                    MessageBox.Show("Launch aborted, Fill in the required fields");
                    break;
                }
                else 
                    Launch_invApp();
                    oDoc = _invApp.Documents.Open(textBox1.Text);
                    MessageBox.Show("Launched succesfully, configurator exe is running...");
                    LaunchedApp = true;         
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
            FileInfo info = new FileInfo(textBox3.Text);
            DateTime ctime = info.LastWriteTime;
            newctime = ctime.ToString();
            oldctime = newctime;
            
//Seems to freeze from this point?

            while (LaunchedApp == true) {
               
                info = new FileInfo(textBox3.Text);
                ctime = info.LastWriteTime;
                newctime = ctime.ToString();
                
                if (newctime.Equals(oldctime))  {                   
                }
                else 
                    AddiLogic();
                    oldctime = newctime;
            }
        }
```

Comment: As a note, [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netcore-3.1) might be the better choice for reacting to file events.

Comment: The loop per se is not the problem, but you are executing it inside an event handler. That's what is locking up your application. If you want the app to stay responsive, you need to execute the loop on a separate thread.

Comment: well, your loop blocks the UI thread, making it impossible to react on user-input. You´d need a second thread which executes the loop

Comment: note that `if (condition) { /* do nothing */ } else { /* do something */ }` should be rewritten `if (!condition) { /* do something */ }`

Comment: On another note: For a program, that "needs to keep running indefinitely", the choice of a WinForms (or any GUI) Application type is not really optimal. You may want to consider making a (windows) service. Or at least a Console App, that you trigger from Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: And one more: `oldctime = newctime;` is executed _**unconditionally**_.

Comment: Why don't you use a windows service which runs all the time?

Comment: @Fildor Thanks! that actually makes alot of sense, i didn't think about the loop locking up  the UI. i'll look into the windows service or console app aswell when i can. I'm really not an experienced programmer, could you give an example how i can place the loop in a seperate thread?

Comment: The question is closed, so it's kinda hard to give an example. But have a look into the question that has been linked to by HimBromBeere, when they closed the question. (see top)